# neccessary and sufficent condition for a $n \times n$ matrix over a ring $R$ to define an isomorphism from $R^n$ to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

To find a neccessary and sufficent condition for a $n \times n$ matrix over a ring $R$ to define an isomorphism from $R^n$ to itself.

Suppose $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix satisfying $Ax=y$, where $x,y$ are $n \times 1$ vectors in $R^n$.

If $R$ is an integral domain or a field, then $A$ defines an isomorphism if $det(A) \neq 0$.

But what about the case, when the entries of $A$ are from a ring (which is not integral domain) ?

**My intuition:**

In case, $R$ is just a ring, the matrix $A$ will define an injective map if $det(A)$ is not a zero divisor of $R$.

But how to ensure the surjection ?

Comment: Are we given that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: @Masmath In general, the equivalent condition you are looking for is that the matrix be invertible. If you seek some kind of numeric criteria for that, you shouldn't expect to find any valid at such a general level. If your ring is commutative, invertibility of the determinant is such a numeric criterion. If your ring is local (not necessarily commutative), lateral invertibility (either left or right) is equivalent to bilateral invertibility.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, It is not given commutative. But let us assume commutative. Then what will happen ?

Comment: In that case, the adjugate gives a formula for the two sided inverse whenever the determinant is a unit